# Why some authors take $A[[t]]$ as $A \otimes_k k[[t]]$ when defining formal deformations?

Tags: formal-power-series, deformation-theory

Let $k$ be a commutative ring with unity and $A$ an associative algebra over $k$. The algebra of formal power series $A[[t]]$ with coefficients in $A$ consists of all formal sums $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n t^n$, where each $a_n$ is in $A$, and becomes an algebra over $k[[t]]$ under the usual definitions of addition, multiplication and scalar multiplication.

In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92718/is-the-tensor-product-of-a-power-series-ring-and-a-field-noetherian) MathOverflow question, it is proved that for a field $k$ the canonical map $A \otimes_k k[[t]] \to A[[t]]$ is only injective in general.

On the other hand, some papers on deformations of algebras seem to take $A \otimes_k k[[t]]$ as the definition of $A[[t]]$, see for example the page 19 in [An introduction to algebraic deformation theory](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82317236.pdf) by Thomas F. Fox or the page 135 of [Algebraic Deformation Theory](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214427886) by W. Stephen Piper.

I have two questions:

1) Why are they taking $A \otimes_k k[[t]]$ as the definition of $A[[t]]$?

2) What is the most widely used definition of a formal deformation of an associative algebra?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Just a ring extension.